# How to hide the border of a Button and a TextView?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I created buttons for entering quantity and it works very well, but there are borders around the Button and TextView. How to remove this border?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/BasketGoodsIcon"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/BasketGoodsIcon"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/decrement"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_left_round"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/BasketInputQttyBtnTxtColor"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/BasketInputQttyBtnColor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/increment"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_right_round"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:textColor="@color/BasketInputQttyBtnTxtColor" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I want these three elements to look like one element.

Comment: update your question with the  button_right_round and button_left_round drawable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your background drawable.xml
make the border color transparent

```
<stroke
        android:color="#0000" />
```